# The behavior for system Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After running my app I get the following output in the terminal. The app does not crash. Where exactly should I put this code? And what exactly does it do?

> 2018-08-16 09:45:05.414410-0400 Yubi[2652:1608362] 4.13.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] The behavior for system Date objects
>   stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide
>   this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
>   following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore
>   methods:
>
> let db = Firestore.firestore() let settings = db.settings
>   settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true db.settings = settings
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read
>   back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects.
>   So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead
>   expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> // old: let date: Date = documentSnapshot.get("created_at") as! Date
>   // new: let timestamp: Timestamp = documentSnapshot.get("created_at")
>   as! Timestamp let date: Date = timestamp.dateValue()
>
> Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new
>   behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new
>   behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add this in appDelegate, where you are adding the configuration.

```
FirebaseApp.configure()

let db = Firestore.firestore() 
let settings = db.settings 
settings.timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true 
db.settings = settings
```

**By setting areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled to true, it will save the timestamps instead of Date**

So, when you read it will return the timestamps, so wherever in your code, there was Date being read, it should now read timestamp and convert it to Date objects as suggested.

**Old code**

```
 // old: This is old code returning Date object
    let date: Date = documentSnapshot.get("created_at") as! Date
```

**Should be replace by new code**

```
 // new: This is new code returning Timestamp object
    let timestamp: Timestamp = documentSnapshot.get("created_at") as! Timestamp 
    let date: Date = timestamp.dateValue()
```

Hope it helps you to understand the warning. You must make the changes to your existing code to meet the new guidelines, or later it will leads to crash due to type mismatch.

Comment: I did not include the timestamp code as I have no constants which deal with date

Comment: okay  no problem. You may ignore it, this is the general warning for everyone. Probably in future, if you will use it, then you will be aware of the change. :)